# Edited: One Word like Eulogy in case of Superannuation(Retirement)

Tags: single-word-requests

Eulogy: a speech or piece of writing that praises someone or something highly, especially a tribute to someone who has just died.

When the person is retiring from work, what would the corresponding term be?

Comment: Single word requests should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: In my experience, "superannuated" means obsolete or outmoded - is that what you mean?

Comment: @user888379, Wiktionary suggests that it may also mean [*retiring*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/superannuate#Verb) (sense 3) - specifically, doing so due to old age.

Comment: How about _tribute_?

Comment: Cambridge dictionaries define eulogy as "a speech, piece of writing, poem, etc. containing great praise, especially for someone who recently died or retired from work" https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/eulogy

Comment: _Encomium_ is a possibility, but it might be too formal for your purpose.

Comment: M-W has " 'Eulogy' applies to a prepared speech or writing extolling the virtues and services of a person." If you feel the funeral connotation is too strong, 'tribute', as @Kate Bunting implies, has a near-tangible sense << 'Daniel Hannon MEP delivered a tribute, opening his speech with ...' > [[Wellington College; the Master](https://www.wellingtoncollege.org.uk/news-events/the-masters-voice/great-without-ceasing-to-be-good/)].

Comment: If you’re looking for a label for that person, consider *retiree*.

Comment: @StuartF That might be correct, but I don't think it's a common enough meaning to be understood that way. "We're having a eulogy for Bob who retired last week." "Oh my god, I didn't know he died!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the word you've used:

> [tribute](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tribute), *n*
>   something that you say, write, or give that shows your respect and admiration for someone, especially on a formal occasion

Depending on the context within the event, you could also call it a:

> [toast](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/toast), *n*
>   an expression of good wishes or respect for someone that involves holding up and then drinking from a glass of alcohol, especially wine, after a short speech: